# WSO2 DSS error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid Staring element

Tags: java, curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm new to WSO2 DSS and REST Architecture and I'm testing a service that was created with DSS with a data source of Microsoft SQL Server. I created a query below which will get employee information

```
SELECT e.employee_id[Employee_Id],
  e.employee_code[Employee_Code],
  e.name_eng[Employee_Name_Eng],
  e.name_arb[Employee_Name_Arb],
  o.description_arb[Organization_Unit_Arb],
  o.description_eng[Organization_Unit_Eng],
  g.description_arb[Grade_Arb],
  g.description_eng[Grade_Eng],
  d.description_arb[Designation_Arb],
  d.description_eng[Designation_Eng],
  e.email[Email],
  r.role_name[Role]
FROM employee_master e
LEFT OUTER JOIN organizations o
ON o.organization_id = e.organization_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN grades g
ON g.grade_id = e.grade_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN designations d
ON d.designation_id = e.designation_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_users u
ON e.employee_id = u.employee_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_user_roles ur
ON ur.user_id = u.user_id,
LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_roles r
ON ur.role_id   = r.role_id
WHERE r.role_id =
  (SELECT MAX(role_id) FROM sec_user_roles WHERE user_id = u.user_id)
AND u.login    =  ?
```

and assigned to a resource user/{login}. However I'm always getting an error

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-209 ~]$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://54.76.120.61:9764/services/FTE/user/103
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 07:42:31 GMT
Connection: close
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server

{"Fault":{"faultcode":"soapenv:Server","faultstring":"Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter","detail":""}}
```

The query was working fine and I've already created similar tests where the simple get would return results in JSON format. Upon checking the logs it has an error saying

```
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: FTE
Location: /FTE.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getuser_login
Current Params: {login=103}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in XML generation at StaticOutputElement.execute
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid Staring element


        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:864)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.executeElement(CallQueryGroup.java:111)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.resource.Resource.execute(Resource.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:462)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:96)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in XML generation at StaticOutputElement.execute
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid Staring element

        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.StaticOutputElement.executeElement(StaticOutputElement.java:258)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElementGroup.executeElement(OutputElementGroup.java:106)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.writeResultEntry(Query.java:396)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:857)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Invalid Staring element
        at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.GsonXMLStreamWriter.writeStartElement(GsonXMLStreamWriter.java:239)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.XMLWriterHelper.writeResultElement(XMLWriterHelper.java:144)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.StaticOutputElement.executeElement(StaticOutputElement.java:250)
        ... 59 more
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to understand the error and searching the net would produce different answers that I'm not really familiar with. I hope somebody can enlighten me on this as I'm only doing this for 2months.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer to this, there are non-printable characters on the database but it is part of data which I can't try to clean or delete them because they are part of data. Retrieving them on a web service will be not allowed because there is no representation of data that is why I'm getting the error "Invalid staring element" to resolve this I have to enable Escaping non printable characters which is a feature introduced from WSO2 DSS 3.1.0 onwards and can be turned on using the WSO2 DSS UI.

Answer (score 3):

As added information, the Escaping non printable characters can be found in the definition of the DSS.

For the one who's editing the DSS manually, you can add the attribute `escapeNonPrintableChar`to the tag result like this

```
<result element="MyList" rowName="myRow" escapeNonPrintableChar="true">
```